# Windows Server 2003 R2 Service Pack version?

Tags: windows-server-2003, x86, service-pack

I am new to Windows Server 2003 R2. I want to install the latest service pack. After Google, I am still confused - which is the lastest service pack version for Windows Server 2003 R2? SP1 or SP2?

BTW: I am using 32-bit.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean service pack when you say fixpack. If so, it's SP2.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb286758.aspx

Comment: Yes, I mean service pack. For Windows Server 2003 RC1, the lastest service pack is sp3?

Comment: No. For **Windows Server** 2003, the latest service pack is SP2

Comment: A little bit confused. Final confirm with you, you mean for both Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2003 RC2, the lastest version of service pack is SP2?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have R2 or not.  The latest service pack for any Windows Server 2003 is SP2.

Answer (score 3):

R2 in only an add-on for Windows Server 2003. The O.S. version is still the same (as opposed to Windows Server 2008 R2, which is a wholly different thing from Windows Server 2008).

The latest service pack for Windows Server 2003, be it R2 or not, is Service Pack 2.